# Image and document upload/download in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm looking to build an app around Elasticsearch with image and file upload/download. So a user uploads an image or document (PDF, Word, etc.), the image gets stored, and retrieved later by users and admin. It looks like Elastic can import/ingest data from files and images, but it is not clear to me if the image/file itself can be uploaded and retrieved. I just need to know if that is possible. If not I'll need to include another system into my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first to ingest attachment processor for storing any media files into elasticsearch.

[So first you need to install elasticsearch plugin.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html)

```
sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment
```

After this ingest pipeline  processor

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/attachment
{
  "description" : "Extract attachment information",
  "processors" : [
    {
      "attachment" : {
        "field" : "data"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here "data" is your filed name where you want to store media files.

After this you can successfully insert the document into index. for ex .

```
PUT my_index/my_type/my_id?pipeline=attachment
{
  "data": "e1xydGYxXGFuc2kNCkxvcmVtIGlwc3VtIGRvbG9yIHNpdCBhbWV0DQpccGFyIH0="
}
```

The data field wants encoded Base64 String of media files.

So first you need to convert media files to byte array to Base64 encoded string.

Source is : [Attachment in elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/using-ingest-attachment.html)

Comment: I would be happy to select this as the correct answer if you can note what I was informed of by the Elastic Search team, that it may be inefficient to do this.

Answer (score 0):

ES is not a file system, it's just a search engine, you can store your file out of es.

Comment: I agree with your suggestions.